# Telerik Kendo UI Grid Paginator not updating page selected

Tags: angular, pagination, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I am using the Kendo UI Grid for Angular with pagination. When I click on a new page or arrow, it calls the pageChange event which updates the State's skip and take properties and calls a service to get the new data. However, the paginator buttons do not update, so it always appears to have the first button selected with a range of 1 - 25 of x items as the label.

The view is

```
<kendo-grid [data]="results"
        [pageable]="pageOptions" [pageSize]="state.take"
        [sortable]="sortOptions" [sort]="sort"
        (pageChange)="pageChange($event)"
        (sortChange)="sortChange($event)">
  <kendo-grid-column field="myField" title="Title" width="80">
  </kendo-grid-column>...
</kendo-grid>
```

And component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { CurrencyPipe, DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { State, SortDescriptor, orderBy } from '@progress/kendo-data-query';
import { GridDataResult, PageChangeEvent } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';
...

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
    styleUrls: [
        './my-component.component.css',
        './../../../../node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-material/dist/all.css'
    ],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() filters: any;

    private results: GridDataResult;

    rowOptions: any = [25, 50, 100];

    state: State = {
        skip: 0,
        take: this.rowOptions[0]
    };

    pageOptions: any = {
        buttonCount: 5,
        info: true,
        type: 'numeric',
        pageSizes: this.rowOptions,
        previousNext: true
    };
    ...

    constructor(private myService: MyService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
       if (this.filters) {
            ...
            this.state.skip = this.filters.offset || undefined;
            this.state.take = this.filters.count || this.rowOptions[0];
            this.getResults();
        }
    }

    getResults() {
        ...
        this.myService.resultsGet(
            ...
            this.state.take,
            this.state.skip
        ).subscribe(
            (pagedList: any) => {
                this.results = {
                    data: pagedList.results,
                    total: pagedList.total
                };
            },
            e => console.log(`error: ${e}`)
        );
    }

    protected pageChange({ skip, take }: PageChangeEvent): void {
        this.state.skip = skip;
        this.state.take = take;
        this.getResults();
    }
}
```

Is there something else that needs to be updated to get the paginator to update the results? I didn't see any other properties on the GridDataResult (such as start or skip) to help with this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `skip` property also needs to be bound to the Grid state, so that the current page is updated correctly:

```
<kendo-grid [data]="results"
    [pageable]="pageOptions" [pageSize]="state.take" [skip]="state.skip"
    [sortable]="sortOptions" [sort]="sort"...
```

If several data operations are enabled simultaneously (like paging, sorting, filtering, etc.), the more convenient approach would be to use the `dataStateChange` event instead and manipulate the whole state like in the following example:

[Grid with data operations](http://plnkr.co/edit/Tsc5ZZQMhG85O3t9oNAO?p=preview)

Comment: dataStateChange is perfect! I was able to merge the pageChange and sortChange events.